# Parse HTML with jsoup and preserve original content

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to replace some elements in HTML files, keeping all the other content unchanged.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div id=title>Old</div >\n" +
        "<p>1<p>2\n" +
        "<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>");
doc.getElementById("title").text("New");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

I expect to have the following output:

```
<div id=title>New</span></div >
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
```

Instead, I have:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="title">New</div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2 </p>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Jsoup added:

1. closing p tags
2. double-quotes to attribute values
3. tbody
4. html, head and body elements

Can I serialise modified HTML back to original? [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/) does that but it doesn’t provide slick DOM manipulation methods as Jsoup does.

Comment: You could do it if JSoup would give you the character offsets of the elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387458/get-character-offsets-for-elements-in-jsoup. We need this feature. Unfortunately, JSoup's author is no longer responding to questions posted to the jsoup google group.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why attribute values shouldn't get quoted? See [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp).

For the other points try this:

```
final String html = "<div id=title>Old</div >\n"
            + "<p>1<p>2\n"
            + "<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("[id=title]").first().text("New");
doc.select("body, head, html, tbody").unwrap();
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(doc);
```